# Qt QGridLayout how to adjust widget width and height

Tags: c++, windows-7, qt4

I am trying to adjust a LineEdit and PushButton width in a QDialog window. The LineEdit should be 20 times wider than then button, so it's long enough to show the whole path. Below is my code, I tried several ways, but they all got similar layout (see screenshot). I want to make the Option window at least 2 times wider to make the LineEdit wide enough. How should I do that?

[image]

This is my code:

```
  this->setWindowTitle(tr("Options"));

  QGridLayout* logLayout = new QGridLayout;

  QLineEdit _logPathLE = new QLineEdit;
  logLayout->addWidget(_logPathLE, 0, 0);
  logLayout->setColumnStretch(0, 20);  // 1st: try with setStretch
  //_logPathLE->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);  // 2nd try with setSizePolicy
  //logLayout->addWidget(logLocation, 0, 0, 0, 20);  // 3rd: try with span multiple columns

  QPushButton* browseFolder = new QPushButton(tr("..."));
  logLayout->addWidget(browseFolder, 0, 1);
  logLayout->setColumnStretch(1, 1);
  //browseFolder->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
  //logLayout->addWidget(browseFolder, 0, 20, 0, 1);

  QGroupBox* optGroupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Log location"));
  optGroupBox->setLayout(logLayout);

  QDialogButtonBox* btns = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
  connect(btns, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
  connect(btns, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));

  QVBoxLayout* options = new QVBoxLayout;
  options->addWidget(optGroupBox);
  options->addWidget(btns);

  this->setLayout(options);
```

Comment: Have you tried this->setGeometry();

Comment: Use QToolButton instead of QPushButton. it should have Fixed size policy so it won't expand letting your QLineEdit occupy all available space in a row.